# Filter chain halted in stripe_event gem on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm developing a Rails app (4.2.x) that uses the stripe_event gem. I'm having difficulty processing the webhooks in development mode. I'm using ultrahook and I'm actually getting the event, however I'm getting a:

```
Processing by StripeEvent::WebhookController#event as XML
Parameters: {.... pending_webhooks"=>2, "request"=>"req_73S67hYD35c8K9", "api_version"=>"2015-09-08"}}

Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007ffc73990350@/Users/mrl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@.../app/controllers/stripe_event/webhook_controller.rb:3> rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Line 3 in the stripe_event webhook_controller is:

```
before_filter do
```

My stripe initializer is as follows:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  secret_key:      ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'],
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

StripeEvent.authentication_secret = ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET']

StripeEvent.configure do |events|

  events.all do |event|
    puts "\n\n\nStripe Event please: #{event}\n\n\n"
  end

end
```

The code works on our staging server:

```
Processing by StripeEvent::WebhookController#event as XML
I, [2015-09-26T10:20:18.909875 #28955]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {..... "request"=>nil, "api_version"=>"2015-09-08"}}
I, [2015-09-26T10:20:19.395064 #28955]  INFO -- :

Stripe Event please: {
  "id": "...""
  "created": 1443262813,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "balance.available",
  "data": {"object":{"pending":[{"amount":5460,"currency":"usd"}],"available":[{"amount":29707,"currency":"usd"}],"livemode":false,"object":"balance"}},
  "object": "event",
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": null,
  "api_version": "2015-09-08"
}
```

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now, and I'm stumped. Does anyone have *any* thoughts where I can look to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this has something to do with misconfigured environment variables in development mode, but it's hard to tell, because the current version of `stripe_event` masks the underlying exception in `WebhookController`.

However, a commit was just added to remedy this and log the full error to help debug situations like this. Please see [Issue 56](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event/issues/56).